# Applied material does show up on object

Tags: materials

I tried to add material on a plane but it does not show up on the object (plane).
Is there a mistake I am doing? (screenshot below)
[image]

Comment: Hello! Have you UV unwrapped the plane?

Comment: No, I haven't. Should I?

Comment: For Image Textures to show up properly, UV unwrapping is necessary. In case of a plane, this is simple: Go to edit mode, select everything and press 'U' , then 'Unwrap'